# Android Studio New Class

Tags: android-studio-2.3

When I try to create a new class in **Android studio 2.3.3** , I get the error shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Made it more readable. Although adding further details like what all was done to analyze the issue, or to solve the issue would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Setting -> File and Code Templates -> Files -> Class.

[image]

Make sure that your class template looks like this

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end

#if (${IMPORT_BLOCK} != "")${IMPORT_BLOCK}
#end
#parse("File Header.java")

#if (${VISIBILITY} == "PUBLIC")public #end #if (${ABSTRACT} == "TRUE")abstract #end #if (${FINAL} == "TRUE")final #end class ${NAME} #if (${SUPERCLASS} != "")extends ${SUPERCLASS} #end #if (${INTERFACES} != "")implements ${INTERFACES} #end {
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I SOLVED THE PROBLEM.